# Create json file for many to many fields in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I need to create json to insert data using inside both models, for tags I have created the json but I don't get how to create json for Question model to insert data directly from it.

model.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Tag_name = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Tag json look like:

```
[
  { "name": "a" },
  { "name": "b" }
]
```

Since Tag_name is many to many field it create 2 tables in sqlite but I want to add data using one json only.How to make a json so that data in both table get inserted ?

Comment: Are you using a custom script to read the json file?

Comment: I have created the json file for Tag using sqlite to json convertion

Comment: How are you adding the data through a json file?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot I haven't added the data from json for tag yet,

Comment: Post the script

Comment: converted sqlite tables data to json for tags so now i have tags json file which i can post using serializers but for Question I have 2 sqlite tables so i can't fetch data from 2 json simultaneously.

Comment: share the code which you have tried?

Comment: data = json.loads(response.text)

        # res = []
        for i in data:
            serializer = TagSerializers(data={'name': i['name'])
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        res = {"status": "success"}

        return Response(res, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

Comment: The above is for tag, i don't know how to write for Question

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose you have read json file and now you want to store that data to db

```
json_data = get_json_data() # write code to read json here

tag_list = []
for tag in json_data:
    tag_list.append(Tag(**tag))
added_tags = Tag.objects.bulk_create(tag_list)
added_tags = [t.id for t in added_tags]

question_object = # write code to get specific question object in which you want to add this
question_object.Tag_name.add(*added_tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for the builtin management command, `./manage.py loaddata`. I think it's easier.

You only need a json fixture for the tag model... the fixture, `tags.json`, could look like:

```
[
    {
    "model":"yourapp.tag",
    "pk":1,
    "fields":{"name": "a" }
},
  {
    "model":"yourapp.tag",
    "pk":2,
    "fields":{"name": "b" }
}
]
```

Store your `tags.json` inside a folder called fixtures inside your app. Finally, run `./manage.py loaddata tags.json`. It will prepopulate the Tag model. Hope it helps...